# Seeking Patterns to Address Concurrent Update Challenges in a Domain-Driven Design Context

Tags: concurrency, locking, domain-driven-design, invariants, aggregates

Our development team is currently exploring effective patterns to handle situations where concurrent updates might lead to data inconsistencies. We adhere to Domain-Driven Design (DDD) principles, incorporating invariants checks within our codebase.

To illustrate the challenge, consider the following examples:

**Example 1: Unique Username Requirement:**

**Problem:** Two users concurrently attempt to register with the same username.
**Consequence:** Both queries to validate username uniqueness return true, leading to the addition of two users with the same username.

**Example 2: Batch Job Execution:**

**Problem:** Two users start a batch job simultaneously, violating the constraint of allowing only one job execution instance.
**Consequence:** Both job executions are started concurrently, contrary to the intended single execution.

**Example 3: Budget Limit in Shopping Basket:**

**Problem:** A user surpasses the budget limit by adding two items concurrently, exploiting a race condition.
**Consequence:** Both additions are allowed, exceeding the budget limit.

After research, we've identified several potential patterns to address these issues:

**1. Database Unique Constraint:**

**Pros:** Resolves example 1.
**Cons:** May not be a comprehensive solution for examples 2 and 3.

**2. DDD Techniques for Aggregates:**

**Pros:** Introduces a new transaction boundary.
**Cons:** Not a direct solution for example 1; effectiveness varies for examples 2 and 3.

**3. Cluster-Aware Command Handler:**

**Pros:** Handles commands in sequence, potentially resolving all three scenarios.
**Cons:** Adds complexity to the system.

**4. Lock Table:**

**Pros:** Can resolve example 2.
**Cons:** Adds complexity; may not address all scenarios.

**5. Database Locks (Pessimistic Locking):**

**Pros:** Can be a solution for example 2.
**Cons:** Implementation complexity.

**6. No Action (Tradeoff Decision):**

**Pros:** Weighs the cost of implementation against the likelihood and impact of concurrency issues.
**Cons:** Accepts a certain level of risk.

**7. Addition to variant 6: Quality Reports for Duplicate Data Detection:**

**Pros:** Offers a monitoring approach.
**Cons:** Reactive rather than preventative.

Our queries for the community:

1. Other Patterns: Are there additional patterns to address concurrent update challenges?
2. Pattern Catalogs: Are there well-known pattern catalogs that explain these patterns along with their pros and cons?
3. Code Examples: Are there code examples of these patterns specifically tailored for Java, JPA, and/or Spring Data?

We appreciate your insights and assistance in navigating this challenge.

Thank you!

Comment: I've been reading DDD literature for close to 10 years now, and I've never seen a corpus of patterns like you describe here.

Comment: I would suggest that the general JPA/Spring Data approach is not going to be conducive to easily applicable patterns in this area.  There are other JVM approaches which will probably help.

Comment: @VoiceOfUnreason is that a good think? Do you recognize and/or agree with the patterns?

Comment: @LeviRamsey could you share some of the other JVM approaches?

Answer (score 1):

Each of the problems presented is unique and each requires its own solution. Here are my suggestions:

**Example 1:**
I would use a unique constraint in the database. I think this is more-or-less the consensus view of DDD experts I have heard discuss the problem.

**Example 2:**
I might have a saga for jobs. There would be an instance of the saga for each type of job. When the user wants to start the job, he sends a command to start the job, the appropriate saga instance handles it by updating its status to "Started" and publishing an event which actually starts the work. Optimistic concurrency on the saga, along with the outbox pattern would prevent the job from being started twice.

**Example 3**
Adding an item to the cart would go through the aggregate root for the cart. Use optimistic concurrency on the cart.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I completely agree with your example 1 solution. The example 2 solution way require pattern 4 (lock table) or 5 (database locks) when your application runs in a cluster (multi nodes). Example 3 applies pattern 2 (introduce an aggregate).